# How to click button from ember.js controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ember.js, ember-paper

When I located a DOM element via:

```
$('md-autocomplete-wrap button')[0]
```

which the browser console actually reveals correctly to be an HTML button, I'd like to click this button through a controller action. 
Nevertheless:

```
$('md-autocomplete-wrap button')[0].click();
```

doesn't do the trick as nothing happens. How do I correctly trigger the `click()` function of this button?

Comment: Is the DOM element you are trying to click something rendered by Ember? If it is, I'd suggest doing this a different way ...

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/mimuwale/1/edit

**js**

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

function getView($el){
  return Ember.View.views[$el.closest(".ember-view").attr("id")];
}

function newAlert(el){
  getView($(el)).get('controller').send('newAlert',el.id);
}

App.IndexView=Ember.View.extend();

App.IndexController=Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions:{
    newAlert:function(buttonId){alert('clicked button:'+buttonId);}
  }
});
```

**hbs**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <button id='definition' onclick='newAlert(this)'>test</button>
</script>
```

Comment: I don't want to overwrite the default onClick method of this button but actually make use of it through calling the click() function.

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery `trigger` method

```
$('md-autocomplete-wrap button')[0].trigger('click')
```

Reference:
http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: I tried this approach but nothing changed in my DOM.